# Magento price rounding (show decimals if neccecary)

Tags: magento

I would like to show price in magento like this:

```
1.00 = 1$
1.02 = 1.02$
1.267 = 1.27$
```

So round to 2 decimals only if there is something after comma, else don't show decimal, is it possible?

I've tryed in locale this pattern:

```
<pattern>¤ #,##0;¤-#,##0</pattern>
```

but it is rounding always to 1$

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a PHP question if I read your question right. Using the PHP round function will get you the output you are looking for, i.e:

```
$x = 1.02;
$y = round($x,2);
echo $y . "$\n";
```

in Magento you can use

```
<?php echo round($variable, 2) . "$" ?>
```

in a .phtml file to do the same thing.